# How to pass a string inside a query

Tags: c#

I have to pass a string value inside a query...Here is my code

```
 string a = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["var"];
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select codesnippet from edk_custombrsnippet_vw where partnerid = 'a'", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

I got the value in string a..but i dont know how to pass that string in that query..Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a parameterized query, for example:

```
string a = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["var"];
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(
  "select codesnippet from edk_custombrsnippet_vw where partnerid = @PartnerID",
  con);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartnerId", a);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

You should *not* embed the string value into the SQL itself - that opens you up to SQL injection attacks. Admittedly in this case it's not a user-provided value, but it's still better not to include it directly.

EDIT: I adapted this example from [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) but it appears that [`SqlDataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx) doesn't actually *have* a `Parameters` property as far as I can see. I've therefore adapted it to use `SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters` which I'd *expect* to work... but you may need to tweak it slightly.

Comment: The question is a classic old shoe/glass bottle question. One should NEVER use string concatenation in SQL statements.

Comment: While I understand your reasoning that the value is not user-provided, I would argue that it should still be regarded as such; the user could very well edit the config file (assuming it's not a web application).

Comment: @Fredrik: True. It's definitely worth using parameters either way :)

Comment: @Fredrik Mork:Ya its a window application..For easy editing purpose only am using this

Answer (score 3):

Not that i recommend this approach in any way, you should at least use [parameterised queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) but to answer your question :

```
string a = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["var"]; 
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(String.Format("select codesnippet from edk_custombrsnippet_vw      where partnerid = '{0}'",a), con); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: This is not recommended because it opens up every possible sort of "SQL injection" vulnerability. A malicious user can supply a carefully chosen value for `a` that destroys your database or retrieves information he should not be allowed to have.

Comment: It is prone to sql injection attacks as well as the issue of single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using paramters:

```
// 1. declare command object with parameter
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "select codesnippet from edk_custombrsnippet_vw where partnerid = @PartnerId", conn);

 string a = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["var"];
// 2. define parameters used in command object
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@PartnerId";
param.Value         = a;

// 3. add new parameter to command object
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```